# Gap between statusbar and view

Tags: iphone

Dealing with this issue for last so many days when button is pressed on the `Mainviewcontroller` it plays audiofile as well as displays `View` with `UIToolbar` at the bottom of the `View`.

`UIView` has `UIImage` and `UIText`

My issue is that when `View` is loaded it shows gap between `status bar` and the loaded `view` and when `infobutton` is pressed from the `UIToolbar` on the `view` it presents `Modalviewcontroller` and when this `Modalviewcontroller` is dismissed back to the `View` it shows same gap between the `status bar` and the `View`.

```
 - (void)displayviewsAction:(id)sender
{

self.view = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]]autorelease];

self.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);

PageOneViewController *viewController = [[[PageOneViewController alloc] init]autorelease];

[self.view addSubview:viewController.view]; 

[self.view addSubview:toolbar];

}
```

Please anyone knows how to fix this issue. Appreciate your help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling for 2 days got the solution for my problem. It was very simple.

I made these changes

```
- (void)displayviewsAction:(id)sender
{
 //self.view = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]]autorelease];

//self.view.superview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);

PageOneViewController *viewController = [[[PageOneViewController alloc] init]autorelease];

viewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);

[self.view addSubview:viewController.view];

[self.view addSubview:toolbar];
```

}

Now there is no gap. It is working fine.